# How to write a recursive function that jumbles up numbers from 0 to 6 in a random manner?

Tags: c++, recursion, random

Basically i want to write a function that takes values from 0 to 6 and gives back a random assortment such as 2,3,4,5,0,1,6. Here is the code that i came up with. However the problem is that the integer prev (meaning previous) does not store all the old values of r (random number) and thus some values end up being repeated. How might i fix this?

```
int s(int b)
    {
        // b is 7
        int h = b-1;
        int prev = -1;// to store the previous r value
        srand(time(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        {
            int r = rand()%(h - 0 + 1) + 0;
            if (r != prev)
            {
             cout << r << endl;
             prev = r;
            }
            else if (r == prev)
            {
                s(b);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have to write a recursive function?  If not there is [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Comment: Why not make `prev` an `std::array` and pass that in? Then you just check the array and ignore duplicates?

Comment: Seed only once.

Comment: I am not allowed to use anything beyond loops and if statements. No arrays allowed. Nested loops are allowed.

Comment: srand should only be called once in a program. rand (and srand) are deprecated.

Comment: If your limit is number 6, you may still transform the array into 7 variables :-/

Comment: I think you have problems with recursion (prev is not shared among recursive calls). Whatever have a look at the simple Fisher-Yates algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle

Comment: just research any shuffling algorithms and read about their pros/cons - almost all published works include code examples in various languages

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, this sounds more like a homework problem than a practical problem because you said "No arrays allowed". But I suppose it is an interesting problem.

Here's some code, in Java with only loops, if statements, and with no arrays, as required.

It outputs a random permutation of the set 0, 1, ..., N, shuffled with the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

```
    void printRandom(int N) {
        long used = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(N - Long.bitCount(used));
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                if ((used & (1L << j)) == 0) {
                    if (randomIndex-- == 0) {
                        System.out.print(j + " ");
                        used = used | (1L << j);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It is unfortunately limited to the size of a long on your system :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this problem is by using an aux funtion that stores in a variable all the numbers printed until the moment, check if the new number is in the used numbers variable, if not add it to the variable (you can use strings? I know that they are arrays of char's but maybe you can)
Something like this:

```
function aux(int b, char *variables_printed, int iterations_left)
  if (b = 0) then print variables_printed
  else
   int n = generate_random_number() %b
   while (n in variables_printed)
     n= (n+random_number) % b
   variables_printed += n
   aux(b, variables_printed, iterations_left-1)
```

And your other function:

```
function s(b)
  if b < 0 return 0
  else 
    char *variables_to_print
    aux(b, variables_to_print, b)
```

If you can not use strings, you can do it with long as konsolas said.